# What is the work done when pressure fully changes in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics

$$dW=-pdV$$
here it seems did the pressure be taken as constant and then what would be the change made in the reaction when pressure is variable.

Comment: There is nothing in that equation that requires the pressure to be constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under very small changes in $V$, the pressure can be taken as *approximately* constant over that interval, so it is possible that this equation will sometimes be used taking $p$ constant.

However, in the general case you are 100% right that $p$ is *not* constant. The trick, then, is knowing how $p$ depends on $V$ so you can calculate $W$ with the integral $$W = -\int p dV.$$

An especially good example of this is for an ideal gas, where you know that $PV = NkT$, so $P = NkT/V$. There are two (simple) cases here: *isothermal expansion*, where $T$ is held constant as $V$ increases, and *adiabatic expansion*, where no heat is allowed to enter the system. I suggest looking into how the work is derived in these situations; this is certainly how I came to understand this slightly subtle issue.

Comment: can you just once tell me the difference between d(pv) and pdV like I an in a bit doubt like why will we not consider enthalpy change as work it is the total change in energy?

Comment: d(pV) is the total change of the quantity pV, which doesn't have a clear physical meaning in general, whereas pdV is a force/area times a change in volume, so represents work. If p is constant, then the two are the same, but if not then d(pV) = Vdp + pdV, so the two differ by a factor of Vdp.

Comment: I mean work = change in energy now the real change in energy is enthalpy change?

Comment: The change in enthalpy is equal to the heat that entered the system, and completely ignores any pV work done. So it seems like you have it backwards; enthalpy accounts for everything that isn't accounted for here.

Comment: Also: "work = change in energy"... this is false. The change in energy is equal to the work done plus the heat that enters the system, per the first law of thermodynamics.

Comment: Ok.One last thing would there be any n thing if we integrated given dpV?

Comment: Assuming the number of particles in the system stays constant during the expansion (which is the case in all cases I can think of), then you can treat N as a constant.

Comment: Ok thanks for answering.