# Two kinds work in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, definition

Follow up on:[What is the work done when pressure fully changes in thermodynamics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/599082/)
We know thermodynamic work is
$$pdV$$
however wikipedia states that going work gone in bringing a system to its state is from its enthalpy article given but:
$$d(pV)$$

So what work is $$nRdT=d(PV) \ what \ is \ its \ importance?$$

so why what work is what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what thermodynamic potential one uses, the work can be either $Vdp$ or $pdV$. To have your question fully answered you need to learn about different [thermodynamic potentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_potential) and how to perform transformations between them.

Comment: What is the meaning what does nRdT give then?

Comment: What is the physical meaning of d(PV) d then.

Comment: Thermodynamic potential has two or three independent variables (depending on whether you work in a canonical or grand canonical ensemble). E.g., it could be $T,V$ in case of Helmholtz free energy, etc. , - as outlined in the linked wikipedia article, and any textbook on thermodynamics&statistical physics.

Comment: Can you tell me just one thing   in a system presure increases p to P and volume v to V then what is the work done  Q heat was released.

Comment: You have to know how one of them depends on the other. E.g., if you know pressure as a function of volume, you calculate $\int p(V)dV$. However $d(PV)$ is not a valid formula to use here.

Comment: work required to achieve its pressure and volume what does this mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy#Definition if you tell this I think everything will be clear ok.

Answer (score 0):

$PdV$ is called boundary work. The work done by or on a closed system to expand or contract the system boundaries, respectively. The typical example is a gas inside a cylinder fitted with a piston.

$Vdp$ is called flow work. The work done by or on a fluid to move a fluid into and out of an open system where a pressure difference exists across the inlet and outlet openings of a control volume. A typical example is a gas or steam turbine. Flow work is included in the enthalpy of the fluid along with its internal energy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cant a system do both togather?

Comment: Flow work only applies to an open system since a closed system, by definition, does not permit mass to flow into or out of the system boundaries. I suppose it’s possible to have boundary work in an open system, but at the moment I can’t think of any examples